# Execute function in inject js web portal from chrome extension background js chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, inject

I have added a file in the manifest like the below code.

**manifest**

```
content_scripts": [ {
  "js": [ "/js/inside.js" ],
  "matches": [ "*://*.google.com/*" ]
} ],
```

**inside.js**

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
scriptTag.src = "chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "helper.js";
var scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
scriptTags.parentNode.appendChild(scriptTag, scriptTags)
```

**helper.js**

```
window.sendImg(imgFile, caption, done = undefined) {
  return window.Store.Chat.find(setPhone(this.phone) + "@c.us").then(chat => {
    let mc = new window.Store.MediaCollection(chat);
    mc.processAttachments([{ file: imgFile }, 1], chat, 1).then(() => {
      let media = mc.models[0];
      media.sendToChat(chat, { caption: caption });
      if (done !== undefined) done(true);
    });
  });
};
```

**background.js**

```
window.sendImg(imgFile, capt);
```

It is not calling, showing error window.sendImg is not defined

[image]

Comment: The background script runs in its own hidden background page. It's like a hidden tab that has its own life cycle: it runs when the extension is loaded, installed, re-enabled, or when resumed in case the background script was declared with "persistent":false. You don't need it here. You currently add the code into [page context](/a/9517879) so only the code in that context can access it like helper.js.

Comment: @wOxxOm, can you please help? Some data are store in background , may be not access in context page, how can I arrange code so that function will execute.

Comment: I can't help using your current code: like I said it doesn't need background.js at all.